# Sending multiple pings in c

Tags: ping

I wrote a code in C that pings a host every second (e.g: ./ping 8.8.8.8). The program sends an ICMP ECHO REQUEST to the host, and when receiving ICMP-ECHO- REPLY, the program will send the next ICMP ECHO REQUEST (no need to stop).

But it only pings once, then gets stuck when I try to receive the reply after the second ping.

Ping Code

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h> // gettimeofday()
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


// IPv4 header len without options
#define IP4_HDRLEN 20
// ICMP header len for echo req
#define ICMP_HDRLEN 8
// Checksum algo
unsigned short calculate_checksum(unsigned short *paddress, int len);
#define SOURCE_IP "127.0.0.1"
int main(int count, char *argv[])
{
    int seq = 1;
    struct icmp icmphdr; // ICMP-header
    char data[IP_MAXPACKET] = "This is the ping.\n";
    int datalen = strlen(data) + 1;
    //===================
    // ICMP header
    //===================
    // Message Type (8 bits): ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST
    icmphdr.icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
    // Message Code (8 bits): echo request
    icmphdr.icmp_code = 0;
    // Identifier (16 bits): some number to trace the response.
    // It will be copied to the response packet and used to map response to the request sent earlier.
    // Thus, it serves as a Transaction-ID when we need to make "ping"
    icmphdr.icmp_id = 18;
    // Sequence Number (16 bits): starts at 0
    icmphdr.icmp_seq = 0;
    // ICMP header checksum (16 bits): set to 0 not to include into checksum calculation
    icmphdr.icmp_cksum = 0;
    // Combine the packet
    char packet[IP_MAXPACKET];
    // Next, ICMP header
    memcpy((packet), &icmphdr, ICMP_HDRLEN);
    // After ICMP header, add the ICMP data.
    memcpy(packet + ICMP_HDRLEN, data, datalen);
    // Calculate the ICMP header checksum
    icmphdr.icmp_cksum = calculate_checksum((unsigned short *)(packet), ICMP_HDRLEN + datalen);
    memcpy((packet), &icmphdr, ICMP_HDRLEN);
    struct sockaddr_in dest_in;
    memset(&dest_in, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    dest_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // The port is irrelant for Networking and therefore was zeroed.
    dest_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    // Create raw socket for IP-RAW (make IP-header by yourself)
    int sock = -1;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed with error: %d", errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "To create a raw socket, the process needs to be run by Admin/root user.\n\n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct timeval start, end;
    while (1)
    {
        gettimeofday(&start, 0);

        // Send the packet using sendto() for sending datagrams.
        int bytes_sent = sendto(sock, packet, ICMP_HDRLEN + datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_in, sizeof(dest_in));
        
        if (bytes_sent == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "sendto() failed with error: %d", errno);
            return -1;
        }

        bzero(packet, IP_MAXPACKET);
        socklen_t len = sizeof(dest_in);
        ssize_t bytes_received = -1;
        while ((bytes_received = recvfrom(sock, packet, sizeof(packet), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_in, &len)))
        {
            printf("recv: %ld\n", bytes_received);
            if (bytes_received > 0)
            {
                // Check the IP header
                struct iphdr *iphdr = (struct iphdr *)packet;
                struct icmphdr *icmphdr = (struct icmphdr *)(packet + (iphdr->ihl * 4));
                // printf("%ld bytes from %s\n", bytes_received, inet_ntoa(dest_in.sin_addr));
                // icmphdr->type
                gettimeofday(&end, 0);
                unsigned long microseconds = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
                printf("Successfuly received one packet: IP: %s, Packet seq number: %d , Time that the ping took: %ld microseconds\n", SOURCE_IP, seq++, microseconds);
                break;
            }
        }

        sleep(1);
    }
    // Close the raw socket descriptor.
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}

// Compute checksum (RFC 1071).
unsigned short calculate_checksum(unsigned short *paddress, int len)
{
    int nleft = len;
    int sum = 0;
    unsigned short *w = paddress;
    unsigned short answer = 0;

    while (nleft > 1)
    {
        sum += *w++;
        nleft -= 2;
    }

    if (nleft == 1)
    {
        *((unsigned char *)&answer) = *((unsigned char *)w);
        sum += answer;
    }

    // add back carry outs from top 16 bits to low 16 bits
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff); // add hi 16 to low 16
    sum += (sum >> 16);                 // add carry
    answer = ~sum;                      // truncate to 16 bits

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program?

Comment: As a possible hint though: What happens if `recvfrom` returns with a failure (i.e. when `bytes_received == -1`)? Please explain that to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: You're right. Although, even if I change it to while((bytes_received = recvfrom(sock, ...)) > 0) the issue isn't solved.

Comment: Well, that's where the debugging comes in. :)

Comment: Looks like you are using the same buffer to receive the response in as you send the request from. But you don't reconstruct the request packet. So you are sending the _response_ the second time, not a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few silly mistakes in the code:

1. `bzero(packet, IP_MAXPACKET);` at line 83
2. `bytes_received = recvfrom(sock, packet, sizeof(packet), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_in, &len)))`  overwriting the same buffer `char packet[IP_MAXPACKET];` which is being used in
   `sendto(sock, packet, ICMP_HDRLEN + datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_in, sizeof(dest_in));`

Solution:

1. Remove `bzero(packet, IP_MAXPACKET);`
2. You can use `char data[IP_MAXPACKET]` buffer in `recvfrom(sock, data, sizeof(data), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_in, &len)))`

Here is slightly modified version of your original code:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h> // gettimeofday()
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


// IPv4 header len without options
#define IP4_HDRLEN 20
// ICMP header len for echo req
#define ICMP_HDRLEN 8
// Checksum algo
unsigned short calculate_checksum(unsigned short *paddress, int len);
#define SOURCE_IP "127.0.0.1"
int main(int count, char *argv[])
{
    int seq = 1;
    struct icmp icmphdr; // ICMP-header
    char data[IP_MAXPACKET] = "This is the ping.\n";
    int datalen = strlen(data) + 1;
    //===================
    // ICMP header
    //===================
    // Message Type (8 bits): ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST
    icmphdr.icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
    // Message Code (8 bits): echo request
    icmphdr.icmp_code = 0;
    // Identifier (16 bits): some number to trace the response.
    // It will be copied to the response packet and used to map response to the request sent earlier.
    // Thus, it serves as a Transaction-ID when we need to make "ping"
    icmphdr.icmp_id = 18;
    // Sequence Number (16 bits): starts at 0
    icmphdr.icmp_seq = 0;
    // ICMP header checksum (16 bits): set to 0 not to include into checksum calculation
    icmphdr.icmp_cksum = 0;
    // Combine the packet
    char packet[IP_MAXPACKET];
    // Next, ICMP header
    memcpy((packet), &icmphdr, ICMP_HDRLEN);
    // After ICMP header, add the ICMP data.
    memcpy(packet + ICMP_HDRLEN, data, datalen);
    // Calculate the ICMP header checksum
    icmphdr.icmp_cksum = calculate_checksum((unsigned short *)(packet), ICMP_HDRLEN + datalen);
    memcpy((packet), &icmphdr, ICMP_HDRLEN);
    struct sockaddr_in dest_in;
    memset(&dest_in, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    dest_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // The port is irrelant for Networking and therefore was zeroed.
    dest_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    // Create raw socket for IP-RAW (make IP-header by yourself)
    int sock = -1;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed with error: %d", errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "To create a raw socket, the process needs to be run by Admin/root user.\n\n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct timeval start, end;
    while (1)
    {
        gettimeofday(&start, 0);

        // Send the packet using sendto() for sending datagrams.
        int bytes_sent = sendto(sock, packet, ICMP_HDRLEN + datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_in, sizeof(dest_in));
        
        if (bytes_sent == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "sendto() failed with error: %d", errno);
            return -1;
        }

        //bzero(packet, IP_MAXPACKET); //Commented this zeroing of transmit buffer
        socklen_t len = sizeof(dest_in);
        ssize_t bytes_received = -1;
        //using different buffer for receiving the response
        while ((bytes_received = recvfrom(sock, data, sizeof(data), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_in, &len)))
        {
            printf("recv: %ld\n", bytes_received);
            if (bytes_received > 0)
            {
                // Check the IP header
                struct iphdr *iphdr = (struct iphdr *)data;
                struct icmphdr *icmphdr = (struct icmphdr *)(data + (iphdr->ihl * 4));
                // printf("%ld bytes from %s\n", bytes_received, inet_ntoa(dest_in.sin_addr));
                // icmphdr->type
                gettimeofday(&end, 0);
                unsigned long microseconds = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
                printf("Successfuly received one packet: IP: %s, Packet seq number: %d , Time that the ping took: %ld microseconds\n", SOURCE_IP, seq++, microseconds);
                break;
            }
        }

        sleep(1);
    }
    // Close the raw socket descriptor.
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}

// Compute checksum (RFC 1071).
unsigned short calculate_checksum(unsigned short *paddress, int len)
{
    int nleft = len;
    int sum = 0;
    unsigned short *w = paddress;
    unsigned short answer = 0;

    while (nleft > 1)
    {
        sum += *w++;
        nleft -= 2;
    }

    if (nleft == 1)
    {
        *((unsigned char *)&answer) = *((unsigned char *)w);
        sum += answer;
    }

    // add back carry outs from top 16 bits to low 16 bits
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff); // add hi 16 to low 16
    sum += (sum >> 16);                 // add carry
    answer = ~sum;                      // truncate to 16 bits

    return answer;
}
```